# Parallel Python: Passing a function written in another module to 'submit'

Tags: python, parallel-processing, parallel-python

I am using the Parallel Python module (`pp`), and want to submit a job to a worker. However, the function that I want to execute is in another module (written with Cython), and I don't know how to import the function name to the new worker. The method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546429/parallel-python-how-do-i-supply-arguments-to-submit?rq=1), i.e importing the module "walkerc" inside the function cannot work since walk itself is defined in walkerc, from the filename "walkerc.so"

```
import pp
from walkerc import walk
# Other stuff here
ser = pp.Server()
# Some more definitions
ser.submit(walk, (it, params))
ser.submit(walk, (1000, params), modules = ("walkerc",), globals = globals())
```

Both the statements above fail, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       ser.submit(walk, (1000, params), modules = ("walkerc",), globals = globals())
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pp.py", line 458, in submit
>       sfunc = self.__dumpsfunc((func, ) + depfuncs, modules)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pp.py", line 629, in
>   __dumpsfunc
>       sources = [self.__get_source(func) for func in funcs]
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pp.py", line 696, in
>   __get_source
>       sourcelines = inspect.getsourcelines(func)[0]
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 690, in getsourcelines
>       lines, lnum = findsource(object)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 526, in findsource
>       file = getfile(object)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 420, in getfile
>       'function, traceback, frame, or code object'.format(object))
>
> TypeError: '<'built-in function walk'>' is not a module, class, method,
>   function, traceback, frame, or code object

The function 'walk' itself is imported properly within the main program, it is the process of submitting it to a new worker that is problematic.

How can I specify the function name 'walk' properly?
I do not want to define 'walk' in the same file as which I have called it because I have modified it in Cython and want to have better performance. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try renaming your `walk` function to something else, `mywalk` for example. As the exception text suggests, your environment seems to have a built-in function that goes by the name `walk`, so the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module gets confused.

I can successfully pass my imported `walk` function like this on my system, no conflict here and nothing more needed, the function gets executed using the given argument:

```
import pp
from walkerc import walk

pps = pp.Server()
pps.submit(walk, args=(1,))
```

But passing [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir), which is a built-in function for sure:

```
pps.submit(dir)
```

I get the exact same error as you do:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "parallel.py", line 9, in 
>     pps.submit(dir)
>   ...
>   File ".../lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 420, in getfile
>     'function, traceback, frame, or code object'.format(object))
> TypeError:  is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object
> ```

### Update after the below discussion:

So the problem here is that Python treats the members that come from [C extensions](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html) as built-ins. The code above works with the regular Python module, but I was able to replicate the OP's error when importing and passing the function from a C extension.

Therefore I wrapped the C extension function call inside a normal Python function, which does the trick. Note that now the `walk` function import was moved to the wrapping function, so that it can construct it's own context itself when dispatched.

```
import pp

def walk(n):
    import walkerc
    return walkerc.walk(n)

def print_callback(result):
    print('callback: ', result)

pps = pp.Server()
job = pps.submit(walk, args=(1,), callback=print_callback)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, that's strange, because when I open an interpreter and import the function 'mywalk' it is shown as `<built-in function mywalk>`. I think it is because I am importing it from a compiled .so file. If I import it from a .py module, it gets imported as `<function walk at 0x7f883a4ca7d0>`

Comment: I guess the real question is then on how to import a Cython module so that it's practically the same as importing a .py module. Thanks for the pointer, I will accept this answer if I solve the problem. :)

Comment: @Abhinav You are correct, I missed that you import from .so. I just managed to replicate the problem. If I import from .so I get the 'built-in function' error too. I'm looking into this further now :)

Comment: Just saw that if you do `import inspect` and then `inspect.isfunction(walkerc.mywalk)`, it shows `False` for a .so module, but `True` for a .py module. The documentation in `isfunction` says that if the object is a user defined function, it returns `True`. And this needs the attributes `func_code` which is not present in a .so module, presumably because it is not byte compiled? So, does this mean there is no way to do it?

Comment: @Abhinav Yes, looking at the same. Wasn't initially clear, but per the [extensions docs](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html) and some other references it looks that extensions are considered built-ins in general and that's how Python treats them, including the `inspect` module. I'm trying to wrap the extension function call in a normal Python function, without success so far.

Comment: @Abhinav I updated the question with what I discovered. There seems to be a solution, I just struggled with C a bit :)